# Error formulario de navegación, solo archivo ejecutable

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

Estoy ya culminando una aplicacion hecha en Access 2013, pero, me he encontrado con un problema, que pensé que era algo de mi equipo o de mi aplicacion, que podía estar dañada. Resulta que la usar un formulario de navegación de dos niveles, osea, opciones en la parte superior y en sus partes laterales, sucede que al presionar, la segunda opciones y solo esta, siempre aparecerá el siguiente error.

**La biblioteca de tipos o el asistente solicitado no es un proyecto de VBA**

Me parecio raro, pero al menos, lo importantes, es que dicho error, no afecta la aplicacion, no la fuerza a cerrarse, no evita la información, no afecta en anda el funcionamiento, solo aparece como un aviso de alerta.

Entonces empece a probar diferentes cosas, para poder deducir, cual podría ser el problema, y sacar una conclusión de este.

- Ejecutar la aplicacion versión ejecutable arrojado por Access 2013, en diferentes arquitecturas de SO, para saber si esa es la causa.
- Crear un nuevo formulario, y probar que no sea algún error *mágico* por parte de Access, los cuales ya me han pasado.
- Probar en un mismo equipo la versión de desarrollo y la versión que es solo para ejecución, y sigue igual, opción para desarrollar, sin error, opción para ejecutar, aparece siempre le problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la pregunta mencionas Access 2013 pero no 2010. ¿Ocurre lo mismo en ambas versiones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buscando en muchos lugares, puede encontrar una solución, la cual evita que la alerta de esto error aparezca como si fuera el fin del mundo. Pero pasa que aun saltando el error, hay que dar doble click a esta opción , todas las primeras veces que abrimos la aplicacion.

La solución consiste en, que en la opción al ocurrir un error en el formulario, preguntemos si es este error, y entonces lo obviemos saltando este, y continuando de forma normal la aplicacion.

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer) 
   If DataErr = -25357 Then
      Response = acDataErrContinue
   End If
End Sub
```

[Enlace respuesta ingles](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/817d7a38-8f04-4816-8d7c-af2745a56b5e/error-requested-type-library-or-wizard-is-not-a-vba-project-with-2-levels-navigation-form?forum=accessdev)

Comment: Esta parece una solución provisional no del todo "transparente" para el usuario final porque según mencionas hay que dar dar doble clic a la opción. ¿Entendí bien?. Por cierto, si la solución la encontraste en algún lado, lo apropiado es hacer la atribución correspondiente como mínimo poner el enlace.

Comment: @Rubén usted lo ha dicho ya edito